# How to safely format a virus infected USB drive in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, virus

So I recently started working as an IT support and I have to plug my USB drive into dozens of computers everyday, at the end of the day or whenever it gets infected I plug it in my own PC (autorun disabled), and format it quickly without opening it. I am running Windows 10 with latest security updates but no third party anti-virus.

I want to know if it's enough or is there an even safer way to do it? I don't really have to be absolutely sure as I have no data worth saving and I can simply re-install Windows whenever I have to, so booting into a live cd of Linux is not worth it in my case.

Comment: if autorun is disabled you are safe, just clean the drive using diskpart from the command prompt, then format.

Comment: Is this a boot USB, and if so of which OS?

Comment: @harrymc Yes it's a bootable USB but not a conventional one as in it contains both Windows 7 and 10 and some bootable toolkits and on top of that some essential softwares. I use winsetupfromusb to create it.